# BIND wildcard in directory

Tags: bind

I'd like to have all my zone files in a few directories (let's just stick with the idea that I can't know how many directories will be there nor what name will they have) and make BIND include them all. (not recursive, just zone files in first folder)

In other words, is something like this possible?

```
options {
    directory "/var/bindconf/*";
}
```

With a folder structure like:

```
/var/bindconf/folderA/my_zone_file.conf
/var/bindconf/folderB/my_zone_file_1.conf
/var/bindconf/folderB/my_zone_file_2.conf
/var/bindconf/folderC/my_zone_file_1.conf
/var/bindconf/folderC/my_zone_file_2.conf
/var/bindconf/folderC/my_zone_file_3.conf
```

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the Bind documentation, [no](https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

**include Statement Grammar**

> include filename;

**include Statement Definition and Usage**

> The include statement inserts the specified file at the point where
> the include statement is encountered. The include statement
> facilitates the administration of configuration files by permitting
> the reading or writing of some things but not others. For example, the
> statement could include private keys that are readable only by the
> name server.

The same thing applies in the options directive:

**directory**

> The working directory of the server. Any non-absolute
> pathnames in the configuration file will be taken as relative to this
> directory. The default location for most server output files (e.g.
> named.run) is this directory. If a directory is not specified, the
> working directory defaults to `.', the directory from which the server
> was started. **The directory specified should be an absolute path**.

Comment: Note that the [newer versions of BIND9](https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#include-statement-grammar) says it supports glob expressions in the include filename, but it's not working for me even on Ubuntu 20.04... so I still use Jørgen's answer as a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you just what to have your domains in separat folders you can get around it by creating a file that holds the content of all the other files:
example:

```
/var/bindconf/folderA/my_zone_file.conf
/var/bindconf/folderB/my_zone_file_1.conf
/var/bindconf/folderB/my_zone_file_2.conf
/var/bindconf/folderC/my_zone_file_1.conf
/var/bindconf/folderC/my_zone_file_2.conf
/var/bindconf/folderC/my_zone_file_3.conf
```

Then make a content file:

```
cat /var/bindconf/*/*.conf > content_file_name.zones
```

Then you include this 'content_file_name.zones' in your named.conf .
Then every time you add or modify one of your .conf files you just rerun the the 'cat' script again, before reloading/restarting the bind service.